# Send bulk message using php mailer with ajax

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I need assistance with sending bulk email.
This is this scanario.
A dropdown contains the categories of emails to be fetched. The selected (value) is then passed through a function that obtains all the emails per the selected value from db. And the emails passed to the mailer's addAddress method.
The sql query works fine but my headers show only the selected value from the network session and not all the returned emails. I am including both php codes and the ajax codes and also the response headers.

**PHP block**

```
$accountid = $_POST['accountid'];


$selectedstatus = $_POST['bulkrecipients']; //From dropdown 
$emailtype = $_POST['emailtype'];
$subject = sanitize_text($_POST['bulksubject']);

$message = sanitize_text($_POST['bulkmessage']);

//Pass recipientemails to function and extract individual emails.
$getemails = getAllEmailsFromStatus($selectedstatus , $_SESSION['username']);

$name = 'Tester';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->setFrom('testproject222', $name);
$mail->Subject = ("$subject");
$mail->Body = $message;


foreach ($getemails as $row) {

    try {

        $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Invalid address skipped: ' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '<br>';
        continue;
    }


    try {
        if ($mail->send()) {
            $status = "success";
            $response = "Email is sent";

            //Save the contact details to db.        
            saveAllEmployerEmails($accountid , $subject, emailtype, $message );
        
        } else {
            $status = "failed";
            $response = 'Something is wrong ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

        exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Mailer Error (' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
        $mail->getSMTPInstance()->reset();
    }
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

**Ajax**

```
       function sendBulk() {
                    var url = "./inc/emailjobs.php";
                    var accountid = $("#accountid");
                    var emailtype = $("#emailtype");                   
                    var recipientemails = $("#bulkrecipients");
                    var bulksubject = $("#bulksubject");
                    var bulkmessage = $('#' + 'bulkmessage').html( tinymce.get('bulkmessage').getContent() );
                   
                    if (isNotEmpty(recipientemails) /*&& isNotEmptyTextArea("bulkmessage")*/) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            method: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            beforeSend: function () {
 
                                $('#bulksendbtn').text("Sending...");
                            },
                            data: {
                                accountid: accountid.val(),
                                emailtype: emailtype.val(),
                                bulksubject: bulksubject.val(),
                                bulkrecipients: recipientemails.val(),
                                bulkmessage: bulkmessage.val()
                            }
                            , success: function (response) {
                                $('#bulkemailForm')[0].reset();
                                $('.bulksendmessage').text("Emails Sent.");
                                $('#bulksendbtn').text("Sent");
                            },
                        });
                    }
                }
```

**Response Form header data**

```
accountid: 2
emailtype: bulk
bulksubject: Test
bulkrecipients: shortlisted
bulkmessage: <p>Testing... </p>
```

Instead of the 'shortlisted' for bulkrecipients, I expect the email addresses. I was hoping to see 2 returned emails. The 'shortlisted' is supposed to be used to obtain the emails for that category (shortlisted).

Comment: Which kind of "header" are you talking about? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase from console. The ajax returned headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "from console"? Can you share more details by editing your question?

Comment: Okay will do. Sorry I meant network section, upon inspecting the page. ie Form data from the headers section.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks generally correct, but this is confusing:

```php
$mail->setFrom('Test', $name);
//$mail->From = ("$email");
```

`$email` isn't defined, and `Test` is not a valid *from* address. I have a suspicion you're trying to use an arbitrary user-submitted email address as the from address. That will not work with Gmail because Gmail does not allow setting arbitrary from addresses; it will only let you send as the account owner (what you put in `Username`), or aliases that you preset in gmail settings. If you try to use anything else, it will simply ignore it and use your account address instead. Is this what you meant by "only the selected value from the network session"?

It's entirely reasonable for gmail to do this since almost by definition anything other than your account address is likely to be forgery, and nobody likes that.

If you want to send email where *replies* will go to a user-submitted address, use your own address in the from address, and use the user-submitted address as a reply-to. See [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) for how to do that.

Comment: I am using a single email as the _from_ address (Please note, I have a completed and working script for sending single mails) I did a few editing before posting (my bad). What I meant by "only the selected value from the network session" is, the returned value by the bulkrecipients 'id'. _I only get the selected value and not the emails_

Comment: The bulk code block works now but now sending to only one recipient instead of the 2 emails fetched from db returned by the function. 'getAllEmailsForInterviewStatus(...) '